# Rspec validates length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm learning `rspec`, I try to valitade length of my model, but I have this errors and I don't know what is going wrong?

```
 #factories/user
 FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
   first_name {"Name"}
   last_name {"Surename"}
   phone_number {"1245767"}
   email {"email@email.net"}
   password {"password"}
  end
 end
```

user_spec: `it { should validate_length_of(:phone_number).is_at_least(7)}`

user model: `validates_length_of :phone_number, minimum: 7`

error:

```
 User validations should ensure phone_number has a length of at least 7
 Failure/Error: it { should validate_length_of(:phone_number).is_at_least(7)}
   Did not expect errors to include "is too short (minimum is 7 characters)" when phone_number is set to "xxxxxxx",
   got errors:
   * "can't be blank" (attribute: email, value: "")
   * "can't be blank" (attribute: password, value: nil)
   * "is too short (minimum is 7 characters)" (attribute: phone_number, value: 0)
   * "can't be blank" (attribute: first_name, value: nil)
   * "can't be blank" (attribute: last_name, value: nil)
```

thank you

@edit

```
 require 'rails_helper'

describe User do 
 describe 'validations' do
    it { should validate_presence_of :first_name }
    it { should validate_presence_of :last_name }
    it { should validate_presence_of :phone_number }
    it { should validate_length_of(:phone_number).is_at_least(7)}
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your whole spec? It looks to me that you aren't creating a user object. By doing something like `user = build(:user)`.

Comment: Have a look at your db/schema.rb file. If the column `:phone_number` on `users` is of type `:integer`, then this might be the culprit. In that case, try changing the column's type to `:string`.  (Reason I am suggesting this: `"xxxxxxx".to_i == 0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an implicit subject, RSpec instantiates the class for you, e.g.:

```
describe User
  it { should_blah_blah }
end
```

At this point the subject (meaning the thing referred to by `it`) is an instance of `User` created by calling `User.new`. This is convenient for some unit tests, but in your case you want to initialize the user with a factory. Use the explicit subject, e.g.:

```
describe User
  subject { build(:user) }
  it { should_blah_blah }
end
```

Now the subject is a `User` instance initialized from the factory definition.

More info in the [RSpec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/explicit-subject)